# Need logic to determine marker size based on point count, interval and chart area

Tags: c#, mschart

I am plotting xy point chart. I need to select the marker size so that the points do not overlap each other based on chart area, total xy point count and minimum interval between points on X and Y axis.

Currently I am doing like this:

```
int marginWidth = chart1.Size.Width;
int marginHeight = chart1.Size.Height;

chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = (((marginWidth * marginHeight) / (marginWidth + marginHeight)) /18)
```

18 is just a calibrated value for about 100 xy points. But obviously, when point count increases markersize needs to be decreased for better visibility.

Can anyone guide me a logic for this?

Comment: Please don't put things like "C# mschart - " into your title. Just use the tags for that.

Answer (score 0):

I see an "easy" solution : set the marker size depending of your data. So instead of "18" you should put chart1.Series[0].Count or something like this =)

Comment: Sometimes point count range between 2 - 2000. Whenever chart resizes, marker size needs to resized based on the chart area for better visiblity. I need only logic how can I include count in the formula

Answer (score 0):

Try This (Calculate the Distance between two Markers)
Markersize = Distance

```
//chart object PrePaint event...     
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {

        //get the PixelPosition of first Marker
        double X1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(1); //X 
        double Y1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(1); //Y
        //get the PixelPosition of second Marker(X-Axis)
        double X2 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(2); //X
        double Y2 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(1); //Y
        //get the PixelPosition of second Marker(Y-Axis)
        double X3 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(1); //X
        double Y3 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(2); //Y
        //Calculate the Distance by Pythagoras (c² = a² + b²)
        //=> a² = (X1 - X2)² && b² = (Y1-Y2)²
        //Sorry is in german but the video explain
        //http://matheguru.com/lineare-algebra/224-abstand-zwischen-zwei-punkten.html
        double disctanceX = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1 - X2, 2) + Math.Pow(Y1 - Y2, 2));
        double disctanceY = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1 - X3, 2) + Math.Pow(Y1 - Y3, 2));

        //limit the marker at smaller value
        if (disctanceX < disctanceY)
        {
                                          //cut the decimals other routines are possible
            chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = (int) Math.Ceiling(disctanceX);
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = (int) Math.Ceiling(disctanceY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, a single line is fine, but it is needed. I've arrived here from a moderation queue because this was automatically flagged. Keeping answers to high quality will help prevent that.

Comment: I hope that satisfies